# Can I install packages by adding the *.deb files to /var/cache/apt/archives and restarting?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, restart

I want to copy some Debian files to a computer that hasn't got internet. I don't want to get a bunch of dependencies manually, so I went to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and copied all the Debian archives to a thumb drive. If I merge these archives to my other computer's `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory and then restart the machine, will it install them for me? Or do I have to manually install all the packages?

Comment: Manually install.

Comment: Is there an easy way to use something like Synaptic to install every file in one go?

Comment: `sudo apt install /path/to/debs/*.deb`, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While apt does download to `/var/cache/apt/archives`, it doesn't automatically install packages from there. To install from downloaded package files, just do:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/debs/*.deb
```

Comment: note that sometimes you need to run `sudo apt install -f` to `fix missed dependencies`.